# Sqlalchemy duplicate entry

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
    purchased_offer = session.query(PurchasedOffer).filter_by(purchased_offer_id=purchased_offer_id).first()
    used_offer = UsedOffer(purchased_offer)
    session.add(used_offer)
    session.delete(purchased_offer)
```

I am just transferring the `purchased_offer` to the `used_offer` table and then deleting `purchased_offer`.

The two tables `UsedOffer` and `PurchasedOffer` only differ by name and are identical with regards to content.

```
class UsedOffer(Base):
__tablename__ = 'used_offer'

used_offer_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
user_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'user.user_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
venue_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'venue.venue_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
offer_message = Column(String(1024), nullable=False)    

user = relationship(u'User')
venue = relationship(u'Venue')

def __init__(self, purchased_offer):
    self.user_id = purchased_offer.user_id
    self.venue_id = purchased_offer.venue_id
    self.offer_message = purchased_offer.offer_message

class PurchasedOffer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'purchased_offer'

    purchased_offer_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'user.user_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    venue_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'venue.venue_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    offer_message = Column(String(1024), nullable=False)   

    user = relationship(u'User')
    venue = relationship(u'Venue')

    def __init__(self, user_id = None, venue_id = None, offer_message = None):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.venue_id = venue_id
        self.offer_message = offer_message
```

My problem is that when I add `used_offer` to the `database`, the `used_offer_id` is always set to `0` so when I go through this process a `2nd` time, I get a `duplicate error`.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Could you show your PurchasedOffer class definition?

Comment: @John I have added it in.

Comment: any chance you have a `DEFAULT` constraint defined on your RDBMS for this field?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set unique value of each used_offer_id (should not always set 0) since you declared it as a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Your used_offer_id is a Primary Key and thus cannot be duplicated.  Delete this attribute (Use del keyword) before you create the UsedOffer Object. SQLAlchemy will create one automatically